# Android Braintree SDK: PayPal Validation Failed|2073 : VALIDATION_ERROR|

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, braintree

There is e-commerce app where we can purchase a product for different countries where we are facing one issue which occurred by doing following steps :

1. Started with the transaction for any country (eg. US) and successfully completed the payment using PayPal.
2. Then again started with second transaction in same session where country changed to UK and proceed for payment but payment failed by giving below API error:

   ```
   Api: PayPal BT
   Response: PayPal Validation Failed | 2073 : VALIDATION_ERROR
   Api response code: 2073
   PaymentState: PROCESSOR_DECLINED:HARD_DECLINED
   Status: declined
   ```

This issue is occurred only in android. In other technology like iphone, ipad, its working properly with the same information(api request). Please suggest solution for this issue. Also, suggest where will be this issue : at android, PayPal Braintree SDK or Backend APIs

Answer (score 0):

A processor decline...is a processor decline. Sending a different billing or shipping address (country) might be the reason it was declined.

It's also possible there was some other validation error in your request, but without full logs it's impossible to know.

If you need to know more about this decline, you should contact Braintree or PayPal support.